# UNO SPI slave read from UNO SPI Master beginTransaction

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

For a project I am trying to understand SPI.

The final project I will use this in, is for reading the SPI from a car radio.

That Radio writes to address 0x80 of a DDRAM LCD display. MY intent is to read for a write to this address and if the bits are correct replace waht is being written.

IE Radio says write the letter E to 0x80, using a mega2560 read this and then interject a different letter then write to the radio screen. So the radio is a master with the Mega and LCD as daisy chained slaves.

I'm using the base code from for [writing to the screen](https://github.com/TonyChatfield/S1-RX8-AC-Display-controller/blob/master/rx8_display_beta_3.0.ino). This was written to fully replac ethe radio so i'm trying to mimic the radio using an UNO as Master and the screen using a Uno as a slave.

I've got the demo working from [circuits4you.com](https://circuits4you.com/2019/01/03/arduino-spi-communication-example/)

I'm trying to modify it to use the same STI settings as seen in the base radio replacement code i'll be modifying for my final project. I know this code writes correctly to the screen. The problem is that the code uses SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3)); as its designed to replace the radio functions.

I'm trying to get that line to work on the 2 UNO's im bench testing with so I can make the mega a slave in the final project.

SPI MASTER Code

```
void setup (void) {
   Serial.begin(9600); //set baud rate to 115200 for usart
   digitalWrite(SS, HIGH); // disable Slave Select
   SPI.begin ();

}

void loop (void) {
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(9600, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3)); 

   char c;
   digitalWrite(SS, LOW); // enable Slave Select
   // send test string
   for (const char * p = "Hello, world!\r" ; c = *p; p++) 
   {
      SPI.transfer (c);
      Serial.println(c);
   }
   digitalWrite(SS, HIGH); // disable Slave Select
   delay(2000);
   SPI.endTransaction();
}
```

The problem seems to arise from the SPI.attachInterrupt() not being compatible with the SPI.beginTransaction is this correct and is there a way around it?

SPI SLAVE Code

```
include <SPI.h>
char buff [50];
volatile byte indx;
volatile boolean process;


void setup (void) {
   Serial.begin (9600);
   pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT); // have to send on master in so it set as output
   SPCR |= _BV(SPE); // turn on SPI in slave mode
   indx = 0; // buffer empty
   process = false;
   SPI.attachInterrupt(); // turn on interrupt

}

ISR (SPI_STC_vect) // SPI interrupt routine 
{ 
   byte c = SPDR; // read byte from SPI Data Register
   if (indx < sizeof buff) {
      buff [indx++] = c; // save data in the next index in the array buff
      if (c == '\r') //check for the end of the word
      process = true;
   }
}

void loop (void) {


   if (process) {
      process = false; //reset the process
      Serial.println (buff); //print the array on serial monitor
      indx= 0; //reset button to zero
   }

}
```

Comment: Please show your modification (use and position) of SPI.setDataMode() in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have got this working now. It seems that it was the Slave not understanding the data mode. I found the SPI.setDataMode() it is listed as Do not use in the reference guide on Arduino.com but its worked spot on for me.